# Can a method call with an anonymous inner class as an argument be verified with mockito?

Tags: java, anonymous-class, mockito

I suspect this isn't possible as the anonymous inner class is private.
Can I verify that the method was called without worrying about the argument?

I'm tying to test this:
http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/using-spring-jmstemplate-to-send-jms.html

With something like:

```
verify(jmsTemplate, times(1)).send();
```

But send() needs an argument.

Is there some other way to unit test sendMessages()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just do `verify(jmsTemplate, times(1)).send(anyObject())`?

Comment: Yep, that's what I was looking for.
verify(jmsTemplate, times(1)).send(Matchers.<MessageCreator>anyObject());